# How get update top style element in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

i want to change top style of one element in html by Angular. its work correctly. let's me explain how it work? i use [this](http://ryanmullins.github.io/angular-hammer/)  for my propose. To change top style i get top style element and when hm-pan event call change top style by this code:

```
var top = $(element).parent().offset().top;// example: top = 300px
$scope.changeTopStyle = function ($event) {
        $scope.newTop = top + $event.deltaY;
};
```

Now my question is  how set top style for second hm-pan call? my mean is when i change top style and hm-pan event finish and again call hm-pan top equal second top not primary top that get in first.